# Does Static Factory apply to C#?

Tags: java, c#, .net-core, factory, .net-core-2.0

I am reading about the static factory method. Does Static factory method coding technique only apply to Java, or can it be applied to C# .Net also? Seems to be more of a Java thing.

https://dzone.com/articles/constructors-or-static-factory-methods

```
class Color {
    private final int hex;
    static Color makeFromRGB(String rgb) {
        return new Color(Integer.parseInt(rgb, 16));
    }
    static Color makeFromPalette(int red, int green, int blue) {
        return new Color(red << 16 + green << 8 + blue);
    }
    static Color makeFromHex(int h) {
        return new Color(h);
    }
    private Color(int h) {
        return new Color(h);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it can definitely be applied in C#, and it's often a good idea - particularly if there are various ways that you want to construct something, all from the same parameter types.

As an example, look at [`TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.7.2). That has factory methods `FromSeconds`, `FromMinutes`, `FromHours`, `FromDays` all of which accept a single `double` as the parameter type.

The factory method pattern also allows for caching in some situations, too.

Comment: thanks for some reason, all the examples I read on the web apply to Java, first time I heard about it when I started learning about Java and reading "Effective Java" from Joshua Bloch, I have read many C# books, and never heard till now

Answer (score 2):

`Static Factory` is a variation on the [Factory Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) design pattern and can be used in a variety of languages, not just Java and C#.

They already exist in C# on the `TimeSpan` class where you can do the following:

```
var seconds = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
var minutes = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(25);
```